# Pixel perfect 2d camera in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a very simple script that updates my orthographic camera on a given resolution so that it accurately scales the view to be pixel perfect.

Here is some relevant code:

```
OrthographicSetting get_override(int size)
{
    return Overrides.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrthographicSize == size);
}

void update_ortho()
{
    m_last_size = Screen.height;

    float ref_size = (OrthographicSize / PixelsPerUnit) * 0.5f;

    OrthographicSetting or = get_override(m_last_size);
    float ppu = or != null ? or.PixelsPerUnit : PixelsPerUnit;
    float ortho_size = (m_last_size / ppu) * 0.5f;
    float multiplier = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Round(ortho_size / ref_size));

    ortho_size /= multiplier;

    this.GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = ortho_size;

    Debug.Log(m_last_size + " " + ortho_size + " " + multiplier + " " + ppu);
}

[System.Serializable]
public class OrthographicSetting
{
    public int OrthographicSize;
    public float PixelsPerUnit;
}

OrthographicSetting get_override(int size)
{
    return Overrides.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrthographicSize == size);
}
```

With this, i can specify a set of overrides for every resolution.

My current setup is using 100 pixels per unity unit. All of my sprites use point filtering with no compression. Yet i still get strange results. 90% of the sprites render fine, but some seem to be rendering incorrectly.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image: BEEP BOOP COMPUTER]

Comment: My guess is that one (or more) objects are not sitting at exact world-space position values.

Comment: @Draco18s  all of the objects are being placed at "nice" positions. For example, (5.04, 2.16, 0). Everything is spaced such that it should appear pixel perfect. I've also noticed that certain sprites render pefectly fine even if i give them a rigid body and bounce them around. And those objects surely are not at "nice" positions yet still render nicely.

Comment: I may have solved the problem. I was using a sprite shader with pixel snap turned on. if i turn off pixel snap the problem seems to more or less go away. I still get the occasional problem with game objects that aren't in "nice" positions, i dunno how to avoid that problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I may have solved the problem. I was using a sprite shader with pixel snap turned on. if i turn off pixel snap the problem seems to more or less go away. I still get the occasional problem with game objects that aren't in "nice" positions, i dunno how to avoid that problem though...